# how can I sort the x axis in hvplot according to its y value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, holoviews, hvplot

I want to sort the x-axis according to its y value i.e. if the x-axis is the product name and y-axis is the average of student who used it and I am using groupby cities so I can choose each city and visualize its hvplot so how can I sort?
I don't want to sort it in dataframe as I am using groupby parameter and certain product maybe more in some cities than others so it won't work unless the order is sorted inside the plot itself not the dataframe

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.